# Run test multiple times with Selenium Webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

```
class LoginTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = Driver()
        self.driver.browser.get(basic_url)

    def test_add_user_uk(self):
        LoginPage(self.driver).login(username, password)
        AddUserPage(self.driver).test_add_user(return_uk_dict())

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.browser.quit()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

I'd like to run test_add_user_uk multiple times.
Is it possible to make it in a loop?

Comment: Can't you add a loop inside the function? You could for example use a counter inside a try-except block inside a for range loop, if you're going for a test based on percentage of succeeding.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but if you loop the test 'test_add_user_uk', the setUp and tearDown methods will not execute with the test after first iteration

you can try the unittest.TestSuite to achieve this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def suite(num):
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        for i in range(num):
            suite.addTest(LoginTests('test_add_user_uk'))
        return suite

    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite(3))
```

Having said that, if you can use pytest, the repeat functionaity can be easily achieved

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/

And you can use the following plugin to run the tests many times

https://pypi.org/project/pytest-repeat/